# Website Versioning Practices

Tags: linux, url, redirect, ubuntu, versioning

I tried searching, but I couldn't really figure out the best search terms to find my answer.

I have a Ubuntu 10.04 server with Apache. I want to set up a site that will be versioned, so my file structure will look like:

```
/var/www/MyApp1.0
/var/www/MyApp1.1
/var/www/dev -> /var/www/html/MyApp1.1
/var/www/test -> /var/www/html/MyApp1.0
```

Where "dev" and "test" are symbolic links to the other folders. So my URL for those two environments will be "http://my-url.com/dev" or "http://my-url.com/test". For my prod environment, I want the URL in the browser to be just "http://my-url.com", without redirecting to something like "http://my-url.com/prod".

How can I set it up so that the base URL points to a specific version without a redirect changing the URL?

By the way, we use MS SourceSafe for version control, so we have older versions backed up as well, but I need multiple environments for dev, test, and prod.

Thanks,

Travis

Comment: Oh dear. Oh dear oh dear. If you use MS Sourcesafe, for version control, you have bigger problems. http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/sourcesafe.html

Comment: SourceSafe works fine. I've used it for years (although I now use SVN), but if you're building a website on Ubuntu, how come you're using SourceSafe? :s

Comment: We're a pretty darn small company, and I'm the only one that really does any web development. Everything else we do is C++ type stuff, and they use SourceSafe for that. Perhaps the best thing for us to do would be to drop it and go with SVN. To be honest, I probably regularly break all the "best practices" rules due to ignorance, but I'm trying to get better :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just check out the right development version to each of your dev, test and 'live' folder. I think it would be easier to just get the right version into the dev folder, than change the symbolic link. Ofcourse you could create a .htaccess file that redirects /dev to a specific version folder, but doing this will just cause you to keep a large amount of different folders for different versions, while what you *should* be doing is put the website in a version control system, develop features and commit them, update the test folder, and if everything's alright, update your production folder as well. 
To do this right you may need to drop SourceSafe.

Comment: I have the Linux box mapped to a drive on my Windows workstation via Samba, so I can have the working directory set to the right place in SourceSafe. I could use it as "checkout->modify->check in", but since I'm the only one working on the project, I found it easier to just keep them checked out. I wrote a batch script to "build" a new version of the site, which checks in the project (keeping files checked out), taking comments from a text file changelog, copying the project to the new version folder, and updating the test link. Is there sufficient reason for me to switch to SVN?